Why does Google App Engine Get Null Data?
I am a beginner in Google App Engine. I am trying to get the data of Klaviyo from Flask to Google Cloud Storage. When I run the code at my computer, everything runs very well, but after I push all my code in the Google Server, the data always gets null. In the code, I have had to calculate the values and I get integer and float data types. I tried to change schema, but the code does not work in the server. Then I convert it into string types, and the same problem occurs.
Please help me.
This is my code:
@app.route("/append_klaviyo_data")
def append_klaviyo_data():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    try:
        dt = data_handler()
        local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone()
        current_time = datetime.now(local_timezone)

        metrics = dt if isinstance(dt, list) and len(dt) == 12 else [""] * 12

        open_rate = metrics[0]
        click_rate = metrics[1]
        unsubscribed_rate = metrics[2]
        bounce_rate = metrics[3]
        delivery_rate = metrics[4]
        conversion_active_on_site_rate = metrics[5]
        conversion_viewed_product_rate = metrics[6]
        revenue_per_email = metrics[7]
        product_purchase_rate = metrics[8]
        average_order_value = metrics[9]
        subscriber_count = metrics[10]
        new_subscriber_count = metrics[11]

        date = current_time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
        results = {
            "date": [date, date],
            "title": ["Active on Site", "Viewed Product"],
            "open_rate": [open_rate, open_rate],
            "click_rate": [click_rate, click_rate],
            "unsubscribed_rate": [unsubscribed_rate, unsubscribed_rate],
            "bounce_rate": [bounce_rate, bounce_rate],
            "delivery_rate": [delivery_rate, delivery_rate],
            "conversion_rate": [
                conversion_active_on_site_rate,
                conversion_viewed_product_rate,
            ],
            "revenue_per_email": [revenue_per_email, revenue_per_email],
            "product_purchase_rate": [product_purchase_rate, product_purchase_rate],
            "average_order_value": [average_order_value, average_order_value],
            "new_subscribers": [
                new_subscriber_count,
                new_subscriber_count,
            ],
            "subscriber_counts": [
                subscriber_count,
                subscriber_count,
            ],
        }

        klaviyo_df = pd.DataFrame(results)

        client = bigquery.Client()

        print("size of dataframe = " + str(klaviyo_df.shape[0]))

        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
            write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND"
        )

        job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
            klaviyo_df, f"{project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_name}", job_config=job_config
        )
        job.result()

        table = client.get_table(f"{project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_name}")

        print(
            "Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
                table.num_rows,
                len(table.schema),
                f"{project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_name}",
            )
        )

        print(
            "Total records logged to BigQuery for Klaviyo =  "
            + str(klaviyo_df.shape[0])
        )
        return "Klaviyo Results Logged!"
    except Exception:
        ex_type, ex_value, ex_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        trace_back = traceback.extract_tb(ex_traceback)
        stack_trace = list()
        for trace in trace_back:
            stack_trace.append(
                "File : %s , Line : %d, Func.Name : %s, Message : %s, Exception type: %s, Exception message: %s"
                % (trace[0], trace[1], trace[2], trace[3], ex_type, ex_value)
            )
        return stack_trace
    finally:
        return metrics

def get_data() -> list:
    try:
        # Initialize variables
        metrics = {
            "delivered_email_count": 0,
            "bounced_email_count": 0,
            "spam_email_count": 0,
            "dropped_email_count": 0,
            "opened_email_count": 0,
            "clicked_email_count": 0,
            "unsubscribed_count": 0,
            "conversion_active_on_site_count": 0,
            "conversion_viewed_product_count": 0,
            "revenue_unique_count": 0,
            "total_revenue_count": 0,
            "total_order_count": 0,
            "delivered_email_unique_count": 0,
            "revenue_count": 0,
            "subscriber_count": 0,
            "new_subscriber_count": 0,
        }
        return [metrics[key] for key in metrics]



def data_handler():
    dt = get_data()
    if isinstance(dt, list) and len(dt) == 16:
        (
            delivered_email_count,
            bounced_email_count,
            spam_email_count,
            dropped_email_count,
            opened_email_count,
            clicked_email_count,
            unsubscribed_count,
            conversion_active_on_site_count,
            conversion_viewed_product_count,
            revenue_unique_count,
            total_revenue_count,
            total_order_count,
            delivered_email_unique_count,
            revenue_count,
            subscriber_count,
            new_subscriber_count,
        ) = dt
    else:
        # Handle the case where get_data() returns an error or unexpected result
        return dt

    total_recipients = (
        delivered_email_count
        + bounced_email_count
        + spam_email_count
        + dropped_email_count
    )
    open_rate = calculate_rate_metric(opened_email_count, delivered_email_count)
    click_rate = calculate_rate_metric(clicked_email_count, delivered_email_count)
    unsubscribed_rate = calculate_rate_metric(unsubscribed_count, total_recipients)
    bounce_rate = calculate_rate_metric(bounced_email_count, total_recipients)
    delivery_rate = calculate_rate_metric(delivered_email_count, total_recipients)
    conversion_active_on_site_rate = calculate_rate_metric(
        conversion_active_on_site_count, delivered_email_count
    )
    conversion_viewed_product_rate = calculate_rate_metric(
        conversion_viewed_product_count, delivered_email_count
    )
    revenue_per_email = (
        revenue_count / delivered_email_count if delivered_email_count != 0 else 0
    )
    product_purchase_rate = calculate_rate_metric(
        revenue_unique_count, delivered_email_unique_count
    )
    average_order_value = (
        total_revenue_count / total_order_count if total_order_count != 0 else 0
    )

    return [
        str(open_rate),
        str(click_rate),
        str(unsubscribed_rate),
        str(bounce_rate),
        str(delivery_rate),
        str(conversion_active_on_site_rate),
        str(conversion_viewed_product_rate),
        str(revenue_per_email),
        str(product_purchase_rate),
        str(average_order_value),
        str(subscriber_count),
        str(new_subscriber_count),
    ]


I am trying to upload the data from Klaviyo to Google Cloud Storage

Please provide a minimal repro of your issue. Your code is incomplete and contains errors. You assert that the code runs locally and fails on App Engine but you don't provide evidence of these statements nor do you include the details of how you deployed the code to App Engine. Absent this detail, it's difficult to help.
